# Connecting to server using Corona SDK

Tags: lua, sdk, coronasdk

So I have found PlayFab and looked into making a multiplayer game, but I first wanted to create a login/register screen once my app opens up.

The problem is I don't know know where to start when wanting to create this. I have looked at their API, but I don't understand what it means. Especially since i've heard PlayFab is much easier when wanting to create a login/register game as it also holds the entire player data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a host to store data on it. Whenever an user register, store his data (such as username, password and etc) on your database. You create a database (MySql) and connect to it by a PHP file. the PHP file get data from your app and insert them to database. In Corona, you write a code that it posts data to the PHP file. You can do this work with *network* plugin.

You can see [here](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/48435-post-data-to-mysql-using-php/).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is highly appreciated !

Comment: Thank you. Excuse me, If I have some problems in wiriting English!